# How can access the documents from DropBox in my ios application

Tags: iphone, ios4, dropbox

I am trying to implement an IOS application. The need of my application is to access the documents(pdf,photo etc) from DropBox Application(My iphone has DropBox Application ) .I am new in iphone development ,so i have no idea about access the document from DropBox.

If anybody know please help me . Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't access documents of some other app. You should use Dropbox API http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502649/accessing-dropbox-in-your-iphone-app

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you will need official Dropbox iOS SDK. Next, you will need an application key, which you can obtain from Dropbox website (choose MyApps). You will notice that the Dropbox iOS SDK comes with a bundled demo application, so have a look there. Also, good starting tutorial can be found [here](http://www.dropbox.com/developers/start/setup#ios).
To access a file, your code will look something like:

```
 NSString* consumerKey; //fill your key
 NSString* consumerSecret ; //fill your secret
 DBSession* session = [[DBSession alloc] initWithConsumerKey:consumerKey 
       consumerSecret:consumerSecret];
 session.delegate = self;
 [DBSession setSharedSession:session];
 [session release];
 if (![[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked])
 {
        DBLoginController* controller = [[DBLoginController new] autorelease];
        controller.delegate = self;
        [controller presentFromController:self];
 }
 DBRestClient *rc = [[DBRestClient alloc] initWithSession:[DBSession sharedSession]];
 self.restClient = rc;
 [rc release];
 self.restClient.delegate = self;

 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SampleFile.txt"];
 [self.restClient loadFile:@"/example/SampleFile.txt" intoPath:filePath];
```

Please note that iOS Dropbox SDK requires iOS 4.2 or greater.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`UIDocumentMenuViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uidocumentmenuviewcontroller) class to access the files from other apps that shares their files. You can find all [`UTI`'s here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009259-SW1)

```
import MobileCoreServices

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIDocumentPickerDelegate, UIDocumentMenuDelegate {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }


  @IBAction func handleImportPickerPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let documentPicker = UIDocumentMenuViewController(documentTypes: [kUTTypePDF as String], in: .import)
    documentPicker.delegate = self
    present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

  // MARK:- UIDocumentMenuDelegate
  func documentMenu(_ documentMenu: UIDocumentMenuViewController, didPickDocumentPicker documentPicker: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
    documentPicker.delegate = self
    present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

  // MARK:- UIDocumentPickerDelegate
  func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL) {
    // Do something
    print("\(url)")
  }
}
```

You will see this kind of screen for choosing the document

[image]